# Scapy fields under encryption

Tags: python, scapy

I have a protocol with encrypted fields.

I want to be able when dissecting the packet, decrypt them
and when building it will encrypt them (lets say I know the private\public key...).

Need this for changing the fields under the encryption.

What is the best way to do this with scapy... 
I couldn't find anything usefull..
maybe something with post_build post_dissect ?

Comment: Ok, for now im doing the encryption in the post_build and decryption in the pre_dissect. If anyone have another idea..:-)

Comment: Just updating, I created packet and overidded addfield and getfield, to get much cleaner and nicer code for doing this. It looks like winning soulotion instead of the post_build and pre_dissect.

Comment: If you answered your questions on your own, be sure to post the answer!

Comment: Yeah, sorry kind of new in posting questions..:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, at the beginning I put the fields behind the encryption in a packet, and do all the encryption magic in `post_build` (encrypt) and `pre_dissect` (decrypt), but that was really tricky... so Instead I created another packet (EncryptedPacket) which overloads `addfield` and `getfield` to do all the encryption stuff, this solution is much cleaner and nicer then the previous one. I will add examples later.